# Function and data not appearing on type ContextProps. React Context with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm getting some vague errors when using React Context with TypeScript to pass things down.

The app works well and displays everything it needs to and the functions work yet TypeScript is yelling at me.

Heres my Context being created.

```js
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

type PokemonProps = {
  number: string;
  name: string;
  image: string;
};

type ContextProps = {
  capturedPokemons: PokemonProps[];
  catchPokemon: (newPokemon: PokemonProps[]) => void;
  releasePokemon: (id: string) => void;
};

const CaughtContext = createContext<ContextProps | null>(null);

export const useCaught = () => useContext(CaughtContext);

export const CaughtProvider: React.FC<ContextProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [capturedPokemons, setCapturedPokemons] = useState<any>([]);

  const catchPokemon = (newPokemon: PokemonProps[]) => {
    if (capturedPokemons.length >= 6) {
      alert('You cannot carry any more Pokemon.');
      return;
    }

    const alreadyCaptured = capturedPokemons.some(
      (p: PokemonProps) => p.name === newPokemon[0].name
    );

    if (alreadyCaptured) {
      alert('you already have that pokemon');
      return;
    }

    if (window.confirm('Capture Pokemon')) {
      setCapturedPokemons([...capturedPokemons, ...newPokemon]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <CaughtContext.Provider
      value={{ catchPokemon, capturedPokemons, releasePokemon }}>
      {children}
    </CaughtContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

When using the above code to use the functions or state in my app for example `const { catchPokemon } = useCaught();` I get and error "Property 'catchPokemon' does not exist on type 'ContextProps | null'." How does `catchPokemon` not exist on type `ContextProps` when I have created the type here:

```js
type ContextProps = {
  capturedPokemons: PokemonProps[];
  catchPokemon: (newPokemon: PokemonProps[]) => void;
  releasePokemon: (id: string) => void;
};
```

Once again everything works as expected but Typescript is telling me something is wrong with vague solutions.

Comment: does it work if you try to do const { catchPokemon } = useContext(CaughtContext) instead of `useCaught` ?

Comment: No it still has the error

Comment: what happens if you remove `null` from this <ContextProps | null>

Comment: Then I get an error because createContext requires a default value

Comment: remove null from the type not the default value .

Comment: Then it says "Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ContextProps'"

Comment: You need to provide a default value rather than null. Something like `{ capturedPokemons: [], catchPokemon: () => undefined, releasePokemon: () => undefined }` should do

Comment: Thats done it thanks!